# What does the enveloping von Neumann algebra functor do to locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given a $C^*$-algebra $A$, we have an enveloping von Neumann algebra $A^{**}$ which is adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of $W^*$-algebras to $C^*$-algebras. Because commutativity is a property that the weak operator topology can detect, if $A$ were Abelian, then $A^{**}$ would be as well.

Now, in the Abelian case, $A\cong C_0(\Omega)$ and $A^{**}\cong C(\dot\Omega)$ (with $\dot\Omega$ necessarily a totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space). What does the functor that takes $\Omega$ to $\dot\Omega$ look like? Is it adjoint to the forgetful functor from the category of totally disconnected Hausdorff spaces to **LCHaus**? Is there some explicit description of $\dot\Omega$ based on $\Omega$?

Comment: It's definitely not adjoint to the forgetful functor from totally disconnected Hausdorff spaces--that adjoint doesn't exist.

Comment: It computes the hyperstonean cover of Ω.  See the work of Dixmier.